# Swipe gesture not working when adding as subview ios sdk

Tags: ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer, subview

I spent entire weekend trying to figure out why my gestures are not working. When I present as a model view gestures are working but when I add as a subview gestures are not working. Is there any reason why its not working only when added as subview.

This code Works:

```
myVC = [[FullViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FullViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: myVC];
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
navigationController.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,1024,724);
```

This code does not work:

```
myVC = [[FullViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FullViewController" bundle:nil];
myVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 724);
myNavCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myVC];
[self.view addSubview: myNavCtrl.view];
myNavCtrl.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -20, 1024, 675);
```

Gesturerecognizer code:

```
swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeLeft:)];
[swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

Any help would be apprenticed.

Comment: Can you show the UIGestureRecognizer code please?

Comment: I initially had the gesturerecognizer in xib. Now moved to .m I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like the superview is not allowing touches or user interaction. Can't say exactly why with the code snippet you provide, but you can try adding a gesture recognizer to the superview and see if that works, if it doesn't then the problem is with the superview.

It works as modal because it does not use the other view at all.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing handleSwipeLeft details:

It looks like you are setting a UIGestureRecognizer and telling it call the selector/ method : handleSwipeLeft.

You should declare your UIGestureRecognizer in your View Controller but set the target as your UIView subclass and then implement handleSwipeLeft in your UIView subclass.

Hope that works